# Google Sheets ImportXML XPath Returns #N/A

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to get a value in google sheets from https://www.mae.com.ar/mercado/datos-del-mercado/mae-today

Here is my formula so far:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.mae.com.ar/mercado/datos-del-mercado/mae-today","//td[@class='market-table-td-value active']")
```

For some reason I don't understand, the result is #N/A. What am I doing wrong?

Here is an image of the value I want from that website:

[image]

Here is an image of the code of that website with the value I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#N/A**, in this case, is a result of trying to scrape JavaScript content/elements which Google Sheets does not support. you can test this simply by disabling JS for a given site and what's left can be **scraped**. in your case it's nothing:

[image: 0]

Comment: Do you know if it's posible to retrieve this value using Apps Scripts? I tried using UrlFetchApp.fetch but it doesn't get the value either